# How to match regexp with ash?

Tags: regex, busybox, ash

Following code works for bash but now i need it for busybox ash , which apparrently does not have "=~"

```
keyword="^Cookie: (.*)$"
if [[ $line =~ $keyword ]]
then
bla bla
fi
```

Is there a suitable replacement ?

Sorry if this is SuperUser question, could not decide.

Edit: There is also no grep,sed,awk etc.  I need pure ash.

Comment: Wow, no POSIX. Just out of curiosity, what system are you running on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *this* particular regex you might get away with a [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) hack:

```
if [ "$line" = "Cookie: ${line#Cookie: }" ]; then
    echo a
fi
```

Or a [pattern matching notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13) + case hack:

```
case "$line" in
    "Cookie: "*)
        echo a
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac
```

However those solutions are strictly less powerful than [regexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) because they have no real Kleene star `*` (only `.*`) and you should *really* get some more powerful tools (a real programming language like Python?) installed on that system or you *will* suffer.

Comment: Thanks this works. As you say it is very limited though. It is a router with very little space cant install perl or python. Might try C.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was using Busy Box's implementations for [grep](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#grep) and [wc](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#wc):

```
MATCHES=`echo "$BRANCH" | grep -iE '^(master|release)' | wc -l`
if [ $MATCHES -eq 0 ]; then
 echo 'Not on master or release branch'
fi
```

Comment: Note that it is better to work with -q option, e.g.: `if $(echo "$BRANCH" | grep -qiE '^(master|release)'); then`

Answer (score 3):

Busybox comes with an `expr` applet which can do regex matching (anchored to the beginning of a string). If the regex matches, its return code will be 0. Example:

```
 # expr "abc" : "[ab]*"
 # echo $?
 0
 # expr "abc" : "[d]*"
 # echo $?
 1
```