# GitLab CI: Bash if Statement in Job wrong result

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab job with a bash if statement that looks like this

```
script:
  - echo $NEW_VERSION
  - export STAGE=staging
  - |-
    if [[ $(expr match "$NEW_VERSION", '([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$') != 0 ]]; then 
      export STAGE=production; 
    fi
  - echo $STAGE
```

The variable `$NEW_VERSION` comes from a previous step. The content of this variable is a semantic version string like `1.0.0` or `1.0.1-develop.1`. If this variable is a prerelease (it contains the develop suffix) I want to set the `$STAGE` to staging otherwise to `production`.

My problem is that no matter which content the `$NEW_VERSION` variable has, `$STAGE` is always set to staging.

If I execute the script on my local mac the value is set right.

Here the log output:

```
$ echo $NEW_VERSION
11.0.0
$ export STAGE=staging
$ if [[ $(expr match "$NEW_VERSION", '([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$') != 0 ]]; then  # collapsed multi-line command
staging
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem or has an idea why this solution dosen't work?

Comment: if you just need to match on the string `develop` could you use `[[ "${NEW_VERSION}" == *develop* ]]` or `[[ "${NEW_VERSION}" =~ develop ]]`?

Comment: Yeah, this was my first approach too but the =~ operator dose not exists for bash. Read here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63124383/10115037

Comment: what does `bash --version` return?

Comment: strange. It says `eval: line 120: bash: not found`

Comment: @Markus Sounds like you're not actually running under bash, or even have bash available. bash certainly does have `=~`, it was [added in version 3.0-alpha](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#conditional_expressions_and_test_command)). The answer you linked about `=~` isn't actually about bash, but the BusyBox version of ash (which was apparently being passed off as bash?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be caused by a wrong syntax in the regular expression and the extra comma after `"$NEW_VERSION"` (which is appended to the value of the variable). This version works as expected.

```
echo $NEW_VERSION
export STAGE=staging
if [ "$(expr match "$NEW_VERSION" '^[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+$')" != 0 ]; then
    export STAGE=production
fi
echo $STAGE
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simpler to use `grep`.

```
if printf "%s\n" "$NEW_VERSION" | grep -xq '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'; then
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the pure bash version with `=~` operator.
Verify that you are really use bash if does'nt work.

```sh
echo $NEW_VERSION
export STAGE=staging
if [[ "${NEW_VERSION}" =~ ([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$ ]]; then
    export STAGE=production
fi
echo $STAGE
```

Remarks:

- Use double brackets with `=~` operator
- Do not put regular expression in quotes

Bonus:

- `=~` is an internal operator, so it's faster than a `expr` call

(tested with GNU bash, version 5.0.17)